# How can I get the current user's ID without Spring Security?

Tags: java, html, mysql, session

im making a Edairy app, and im doing now the StudentGrades HTML page, which should list the Student's Subjects and their grades. It important that different Students have different kind of subjects, so I only want to display the logged-in students Subject and their grades.
(For example student1 have chesmistry and physics, student2 have P.E., Mathematics)

Now im trying to make a method which selects the Subjects from the DB based on the currently logged-in students ID, but I dont use Spring Security. I tried 2 different ways, but both failed.

```
public List<Subject> findAll(Integer userId) {

    
    String sql = "SELECT subject.subjectName,subject.subjectId FROM subject inner join subjectgrade on subject.subjectId = subjectgrade.subjectId right join users on subjectgrade.userId = users.user_id where subjectgrade.userId = ?";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Subject.class));
}
```

With this attempt, the program failed to process the intended task, because the userId was present, however its a primitive type, and didnt like it for some reason:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'userId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
```

With the 2nd attempt, I tried passing an User into the parameter. With that method, the program succesfully ran, but It did not select the logged-in user's Subjects, because I could not figure out how to get the user's ID from the session(?).

```
public List<Subject> findAll(User user) {

    
    String sql = "SELECT subject.subjectName,subject.subjectId FROM subject inner join subjectgrade on subject.subjectId = subjectgrade.subjectId right join users on subjectgrade.userId = users.user_id where subjectgrade.userId = "+ user.getUserId();
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Subject.class));
}
```

Its important to note, that Im not using Spring Security, because Im just practicing coding. Can I get the user's ID without rebulding my whole program? Or did I commit a huge logical flaw which made me come to a halt?
(?) = not sure how to call it.

Comment: How does your subject class look like? In your first attempt the provided userId is not a primitive type. Integer is a wrapper for the primitive int and can therefore be null.

Comment: my subject class only consists of getters and setters and their attributes. I defined the subjectId as int, not Integer there. Is that a problem?

Comment: Sure: As the exception says the `user_id` is of type `int` which is a primitive type and not except the NULL value. You need to use the `Integer` class which is a wrapper type for int which allows NULL values

Comment: You are the best Daniel, never thought its that sensitive.
Can you recommend me a way to get the User's id without Spring Security?
The program now will work the way I intended it.

Comment: You are welcome. Posted the comment as answer so you can accept it.
You should be more precise at `Can you recommend me a way to get the User's id without Spring Security`. How do you currently obtain the userId?

Comment: @PostMapping("/login")
 public String doLogin(@RequestParam String htmlusername, Model model) {
  htmlusername = request.getParameter("htmlusername");
  String password = request.getParameter("htmlpassword");
I use requestParameters to get the userName and password.
Then the program lists the users. If they find a User object with the right name and password combination, the program lets them log-in.

Comment: Hmm I am currently thinking about what spring security has to do with the user id. It reads like you manage the users by yourself meaning you already store somewhere the user data which also should contain an identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says the `user_id` is of type `int` which is a primitive type. Primitive types can not be `NULL`.

To use NULL for int values you need to use the corresponding wrapper class called `Integer` which allows the assignment of `NULL`.